# How to Show Login Interface based on GoogleApiClient state

Tags: android, google-plus, google-api-client

As a base I'm using this tutorial https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in -- implemented in an Abstract BaseActivity that is inherited by my application activities.

I would like to show a login interface if the user is not logged in.  The logic is currently residing in a method that is called from onConnectionFailed as follows:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user clicks
        // 'sign-in'.
        mConnectionResult = connectionResult;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();
        } else {
            showLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best method to show the login interface?

Should I use a ViewGroup/Layout or encapsulate the login interface and logic within a fragment?

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't just launch a new activity with the login interface.

Comment: I think when I ran through the sample it calls onConnected or something like that when the user is signed in.

Comment: @Nathan Walters - I could launch an activity, but it seems like a lot of overhead for a simple task of showing a Google Sign-in Button.  That is why I was leaning towards either a fragment or updating the RootView with a new layout.

Comment: @danny117 - That is correct, but as per above, I want to know the best way to show a login interface when the user is not logged in

Comment: @meandnotyou there's very, very little overhead in creating an activity, I wouldn't worry about that. Logging in is exactly the kind of focused task that Activites are perfect for.

Comment: What I'm saying is I think the way the sample is setup the login only shows whens the user is not logged in so you are already done.  It's automatic.  Onconnectionfailed only gets called when the user is not logged in.  Good Luck @meandnotyou with your app.